# How to declare which certificate for service to use with Backend HTTPS?

Tags: https, kubernetes, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine

I found this example of setting up a service to do SSL termination on a backend service as opposed to on the ingress controller, but I don't see where to specify which certificate to use. I'd like to use a certificate I already have in my Google cloud certificate store. Where do I set that? How does this example work without a certificate?

https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-gce/blob/master/examples/backside-https/app.yaml

More information about frontend vs backend HTTPS: https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-gce/blob/master/README.md#frontend-https

Answer (score 0):

If the backend service is using a certificate signed by a public CA, then nothing needs to be done. The GKE ingress is just like any other client to your backend- it knows about various certificate authorities and it can verify that your backend certificate was signed by one of those authorities.

If however the certificate in your certificate store is a client certificate, meaning that you want GKE to be authenticating using that certificate to your backend, not sure that is possible.

There is a way to instruct nginx to use client certificates, something along the lines of this answer, which uses self-signed certificates:

https://serverfault.com/a/717926/370529

And there is a way to provide those snippets to an nginx ingress controller. But GKE does not use nginx. I don't know of a way to do the same with the GKE ingress controller.

Comment: "If the backend service is using a certificate" is precisely the problem I'm trying to solve. How do I know which certificate it is using if it isn't declared in any of the YAML files? Notice that the example YAML file has no mention of a certificate yet it's supposed to be able to terminate SSL.

Comment: In general an app with the ability to terminate ssl on its own should be configured to take a cert and a private key. In this case, though, the app.yaml is deploying google's example echoserver. The echoserver, at startup, generates a self-signed cert: https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/935a5ef2c8dc19888b89e675e625aeaffc938689/images/echoheaders/run.sh

Comment: I have not used gcloud extensively but fwiw my sense is that certificates in gcloud certificate store can really only be automagically used in gcloud load balancers. To use one of those certs in an application deployed in k8s, there would need to be a way to export the cert to files. Those files could be loaded into a cluster in secrets, and then mounted by the application pod.